compile gcc on openbsd for libgccjit -- unable to find libc.a
I have cloned gcc repo from (https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/releases/gcc-13). Configured within build directory as such:
../configure --enable-host-shared --enable-languages=jit,c++ --disable-bootstrap --enable-checking=release --prefix=/usr/local --with-gmp=/usr/local  --with-mpfr=/usr/local --with-mpc=/usr/local --build=x86_64-unknown-openbsd$(uname -r) --host=x86_64-unknown-openbsd$(uname -r)  --target=x86_64-unknown-openbsd$(uname -r) --prefix=/home/kabiraatmonallabs/Execution/Runtime  --enable-threads   --disable-multilib --enable-lto --disable-libstdcxx-pch --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as -with-gnu-ld

Followed by gmake. The compile fails in the directory x86_64-unknown-openbsd7.5/libgomp. The config.log says:
configure:3898: /home/kabiraatmonallabs/Execution/Runtime/gcc/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/kabiraatmonallabs/Execution/Runtime/gcc/build/./gcc/ -B/home/kabiraatmonallabs/Execution/Runtime/x86_64-unknown-openbsd7.5/bin/ -B/home/kabiraatmonallabs/Execution/Runtime/x86_64-unknown-openbsd7.5/lib/ -isystem /home/kabiraatmonallabs/Execution/Runtime/x86_64-unknown-openbsd7.5/include -isystem /home/kabiraatmonallabs/Execution/Runtime/x86_64-unknown-openbsd7.5/sys-include    -g -O2   conftest.c  >&5
ld: error: unable to find library -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The libc.so and libc.a is in its usual /usr/lib location. Not sure why xgcc not able to compile the code.

You seem to be using a lot of flags that are not needed to compile libgccjit. Does it work if you use only the flags shown in the doc?
